# $\mathcal{A}$ algebra. Show that $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $\Sigma(\mathcal{A})$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu(X)<\infty$. Let $d$ be a function:

$d: Pot(X) \times Pot(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (A,B) \mapsto d(A,B)=\mu((A\cup B)\setminus(A \cap B))$

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an algebra. Show that $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $\Sigma(\mathcal{A})$ that means: for all $M\in \Sigma(\mathcal{A})$ exists a sequence $(M_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subset \mathcal{A}$ with $d(M_{n},M)\rightarrow 0$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$.

There is a hint given: Show that the closure of $\mathcal{A}$ is a Dynkin system regarding $d$.

My question is: What does this hint tell me? Also I don't know how $\Sigma(\mathcal{A})$ looks like. I know that it is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathcal{A}... I have no idea where to start. 
It would be nice if you can give me some advice.

Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note first that your $d$ is basically the measure of symmetric difference operator for sets i.e. $d(A,B)=\mu(A\Delta B)$.

You have to show denseness of $\mathcal A$ in $ \mathcal M=\Sigma(\mathcal A)$ i.e. given $\epsilon>0$ and any $B\in\mathcal M$, you need to show there exists $A\in\mathcal A$ such that $\mu(A\Delta B)<\epsilon$.

I am not very comfortable with pi and D-systems, so I will follow the good old roue: showing something is a $\sigma-$algebra.

Now I will not do everything for you but outline what can be an easy way to tackle this problem.

Define $\mathcal F=\{B\in M:\forall \epsilon>0$ there exists $A\in\mathcal A$ with $\mu(A\Delta B)<\epsilon\}$. Show that $\mathcal A\subset\mathcal F$. This is trivial.

Now show that $\mathcal F$ is a $\sigma-$algebra. This is essentially where you will need to choose $\epsilon$'s carefully, and use the facts that $A\Delta B=A^c\Delta B^c$ and $\big(\bigcup A_n\big)\Delta \big(\bigcup B_n\big)\subseteq \bigcup (A_n\Delta B_n)$.

So once you show $\mathcal F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal A$, it follows that $\mathcal F\supseteq \Sigma(\mathcal A)=\mathcal M$, but since by definition, $\mathcal F\subseteq\mathcal M$, it follows $\mathcal F=\mathcal M$. The stated property is therefore true for every $B\in\mathcal M$.